# C++ type alias with using keyword

Tags: c++, c++17, typedef, type-alias

Is it possible to define such type alias with `using` keyword in c++?
How would be the syntax? I have tried `using const_type = typename const T::type` it doesn’t work.

```
template <typename T>
    class DoubleBuffer {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T const & const_reference;
    typedef T* pointer;

    const_reference operator[](const size_t pos){
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: `using const_type = const typename T::type;`

Comment: `using const_type = const T;`

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to replace all `typedef`s in your example with the `using` keyword?

Comment: @InnocentBystander yes, but I am really confused when to use `typename` when not to use. it seems that's the issue on my code.

Comment: @evanxg852000 see section **The typename disambiguator for dependent names** under [Dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class DoubleBuffer {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const &;
    using const_type = const typename T::type;
    using pointer = T*;
    //...
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/wHT6w8)

Or:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class DoubleBuffer {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const &;
    using const_type = const T;
    using pointer = T*;
    //...
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/MGFqQQ)

Depending on what `T` actually is - a `struct`/`class` with a nested `type` defined, or a standalone type.

Comment: Please, any documentation that points to why `typename` is used in some circumstances `using const_type = const typename T::type;` ?

Comment: You have to use [`typename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) when referring to a nested type whose parent type is dependent on a template.

Comment: @evanxg852000 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords